# String format Java

Tags: java, string, format

I would like to do the following thing:

I have a String in Java, for instance

> "4231354"

My aim is to show a version number in this way

> XXX-X-X.XX

which means than I need to use a function to show

> "423-1-3.54"

Thanks.

Comment: show your attempts? Is the string always have fixed number of digits?

Comment: I am trying to use the `String.format()` method but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I always use the same number of digits.

Comment: `String` has a `substring(int,int)` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `replaceAll`, like this:

```
String ver = "4231354";
String fmt = ver.replaceAll("(\\d{3})(\\d)(\\d)(\\d{2})", "$1-$2-$3.$4");
```

Regular expression defined by the first parameter has four groups - a group of three characters, two groups of single characters, and a group of two characters. The second parameter uses these groups, which are numbered `$1` through `$4`, to produce the formatting that you are looking to achieve.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/nM2nG4)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this too:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("4235167");

    str.insert(3, '-');
    str.insert(5, '-');
    str.insert(7, '.');
    System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the old way

As you mentioned length is fixed so you can use substring

```
String st="4231354";
String newString=st.substring(0,3)+"-"+st.substring(3,4)+"-"+st.substring(4,5)+"."+st.substring(5,st.length());
System.out.println(newString);
```

#### DEMO

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get 
"423-1-3.54"
All you have to do is:

```
String originalNumber = "4231354";
String versionNumber = new String(originalNumber.substring(0, 3) + "-" + originalNumber.substring(3, 4) + "-" + originalNumber.substring(4, 5) + "." + originalNumber.substring(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use String.format()

```
    public Format(String version) {
        String v = String.format("%s-%s-%s.%s", 
            version.substring(0,3), 
            version.substring(3,4), 
            version.substring(4,5), 
            version.substring(5,7)); 
        System.out.println(v);
    }
```